# How to change Ghostscript output file (in printer spooler)

Tags: ghostscript

I am using Ghostscript to print a PDF by command line arguments. But it shows the printed document's name as Ghostscript output in printer spooler. I want to change it to a custom name (as input file name).

Answer (score 0):

**`man gs`**

```
-sOutputFile=filename
    Selects an alternate output file (or pipe) for the initial output device,
    as described above.
```

Comment: i mean to say when i print a pdf using Ghostscript then that file goes in printer spooler with name "ghostscript output" . that thing i want to change